# How to inherit computed properties from model?

Tags: inheritance, model, ember.js

It is pretty straightforward to inherit attributes from an existing model, but I noticed that computed properties don't work as expected. Is there a workaround to inherit computed properties as well?

Comment: Do you have an example, where it does not work? It works for me.

Comment: You are correct. I was accessing the computed properties incorrectly.